# Replacing an older version monero-wallet-gui.app with a newer version

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I have the Macintosh monero-wallet-gui.app I downloaded long ago, but there's no version information, say's "Created by Qt/QMake" in the file's version field. The files 'modified:' field is 'October 25, 2017'

The new version I just downloaded has "- -" in the version field, 'modified' field is October 15, 2018. How does one tell what the version number is?

When I start the app, will it figure out where the blockchain is without me having to do anything?

(Sorry if this is a dup, the 'similar questions' link addressed Windows, didn't find it specifically for Mac)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The version, if I recall correctly, is in the Settings tab and shows both GUI and daemon versions.

And yes, if you didn't change the default blockchain location, upgrades will still find the previously downloaded blockchain.

Comment: Well, the one I just downloaded crashes just after it asks if I want to launch it with "Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing".

is it any use to run the older version until the new one is fixed?

Comment: The version currently installed is 'GUI version: v0.11.1.0', and 'Embedded Monero version: v0.11.1.0-2-gc328163'.  The daemon version isn't displayed (thst I can see)

I have a crash log, would that help? Who do I send it to?

Thanks!

I didn't hear about v0.12…

Comment: The "Embedded" version is the daemon. Latest release (0.13.0.3) is available at https://src.getmonero.org/downloads/ and there is a version 0.13.0.4 which is about to be released. As for the missing library error, that will be fixed in the .4 release, or if you cannot wait, there are posts that detail how it can be fixed on Reddit/SE. One thing for sure though, you cannot use v0.11.